# Position Coordinates vs time for perfect circular motion in any number of spatial dimensions and assuming total speed of 1?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

If something has certain initial position coordinates, and certain initial velocity coordinates, its total speed is always 1, and assuming the circle has its center at the origin or the point with a value of 0 in every spatial dimension, what would be the most general parametric equation for the position coordinates vs time of the object that applies to any number of spatial dimensions?

Comment: The radius is a constant, so the sum of the squares of the coordinates is constant.  The initial radius vector and the initial velocity vector determine a plane.  All motion takes place in that plane.  You need the initial velocity to be perpendicular to the initial radius and the initial speed to be $1$.  All of this is true in any number of dimensions.  Probably the easiest approach is to start with the starting point being $(r,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and the starting velocity being $(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: The position at time $t$ is $(r \cos (\omega t), r\sin (\omega t),0,0,0,\ldots)$ with $\omega=\frac 1{2 \pi r}$.  Now rotate the coordinates to make the starting position and velocity correct.